# Ordering of Nested Elements in Mozilla react-jsonschema-form

Tags: forms, reactjs, mozilla

Is there a way to create UI order on nested elements when ordering is required at both the parent and child ?

For Eg:

In the nested example on the playground, If I had to wanted to get the tasks before and title and also tasks->details before tasks->title and if title had mainTitle and subTitle which also had to be ordered, Can someone please give an example ?

JSON Schema:

```
{ "title": "A list of tasks", "type": "object", "required": [ "title" ], "properties": { "title": { "type": "string", "title": "Task list title" }, "tasks": { "type": "array", "title": "Tasks", "items": { "type": "object", "required": [ "title" ], "properties": { "title": { "type": "object", "required": [ "main" ], "properties": { "main": { "type": "string", "description": "Enter the main title" }, "subtitle": { "type": "string", "description": "Enter the subtitle" } } }, "details": { "type": "string", "title": "Task details", "description": "Enter the task details" }, "done": { "type": "boolean", "title": "Done?", "default": false } } } } } }
```

FormData:

```
{ "title": "My current tasks", "tasks": [ { "title": { "main": "main title" }, "details": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.", "done": true }, { "title": { "main": "main title" }, "details": "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur", "done": false } ] }
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.